# Obtaining location prompt on ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I am trying to implement location access prompt in ionic 3 but unable to find how to implement this type of prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This prompt is triggered when you ask for the location of the user for the first time.

The message displayed in iOS can be set by adding this key in the `config.xml`

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
   <string>This is the message which will be displayed to the user</string>
</edit-config>
```

If you want to always have the location of your user, you have to set this key :

```
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Comment: On Android, you cannot modify the location authrorization prompt text